# Test Explorer in Visual Studio: How do I order tests based on the attribute [Order(1)]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Couldn't find any info about this..

I want my **NUnit** tests to be sorted based on the **Order** attribute assosiated with the test in **Test Explorer**.
I have tried grouping by trait, but still it is ordered alphabetically.

Example

```
[Order(1)] 
[Test] 
public void PublishXXX()
{
  // Publish a message
}

[Order(2)]
[Test]
public void ConsumeXXX()
{
  // Consume the message
}
```

Do I need to rename the tests to include 01_Publishxxx, and 02_Consume event though I have included the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The **Order** attribute is used by the NUnit framework to run multiple tests within a fixture in the order specified.

Older versions of Visual Studio Test Explorer just told NUnit to run all the tests you selected. At some point (I'm not sure but maybe VS 2022?) Test Explorer started calling the NUnit adapter with a list of  tests to run. That order of that list is probably superseding the order NUnit would use.

You check if this is true in a few ways...

1. Run the tests under NUnit console runner or using NUnitLite.
2. If you have an older version of VS around, try using that.

For a better answer, you should probably edit your question to specify what software versions you are actually using (both VS and NUnit adapter versions).